# Should I vote negative for questions that has problem irrespective of negative votes and comments?

Tags: discussion

Often I read questions that has already been downvoted, sometimes with valid comment to suggest improvement.

Sometime I add comment to suggest improvement. At that very moment I feel I should not down vote further, giving OP opportunity to understand what's wrong with the question and let OP improve it.

I am not sure if this is the right way of thinking.

So should we downvote right after reading the question (once we know the question needs improvement or does not comply with SO standard)?

OR

Should we consider If X (what would be X?) user already downvoted and there are valid comment to suggest OP to make improvement or delete post?